# New vue component instance when prop changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Our single page application has different views based on components. Due to the one-way-dataflow each property in the child gets updated when the respective value bound in the parent changes.

Is it possible to get a completely new component instance in case a property has changed? In combination with a transition I want to achieve that the old component slides out while the new one based on the latest property values slides in.

I am really looking forward for some cool input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by updating the key:

```
<transition name="fade">
  <hello :key="key"></hello>
</transition>
```

Then update the key:

```
<button @click="key++">Reload</button>
```

See my example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/eaguad1337/w9fb1pv2/

Comment: That looks promising! I'll give it a try.

Comment: I've just included this approach in my current project and it works. Thanks a lot! The only small downside is, that I have to change the key for those kind of transitions in addition. Based on params would be the best.